# UnsupportedOperationException when retrieving all nodes with GlobalGraphOperations in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm using neo4j 1.8.2 and am trying to retrieve all nodes from a graph, but I am getting UnsupportedOperationException.

```
GraphDatabaseService db = GraphDatabaseFactory.databaseFor("http://localhost:7474/db/data/");
Iterable<Node> nodes = GlobalGraphOperations.at(db).getAllNodes();
```

I found it in the API documentation, so I can't understand, what am I doing wrong.

Comment: It might be interesting to see your stacktrace

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
 at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.AbstractRemoteDatabase.getNodeManager(AbstractRemoteDatabase.java:144)
 at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestGraphDatabase.getNodeManager(RestGraphDatabase.java:33)
 at org.neo4j.tooling.GlobalGraphOperations.<init>(GlobalGraphOperations.java:39)
 at org.neo4j.tooling.GlobalGraphOperations.at(GlobalGraphOperations.java:51)
 at ru.tests.main.main(main.java:17)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you find it?

The **REST** Graph Database doesn't support this operation (or at least not if called from `GlobalGraphOperations`

The `db.getAllNodes()` is implemented using a remote cypher query which is what you should do as well.

```
new RestCypherQueryEngine(restGraphDb.getRestAPI()).query(....)
```

or

```
restGraphDB.query()
```

Comment: I found it here http://api.neo4j.org/1.8.2/org/neo4j/tooling/GlobalGraphOperations.html

Thanks for the answer=)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can't do this with a remote database. Check [the source](https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding/blob/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/rest/graphdb/AbstractRemoteDatabase.java), it frequently throws UnsupportedOperationExceptions. Maybe an embedded database is an option for you?